# Why Express Route Isn't storing cache when done within another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

When I call my code from within another file, the caching doesn't work, but when I keep it in the same file it works.  Can someone help me figure out why the caching isn't happening when I use my middleware file

Working code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var cache = require('../middleware/cache');
var controller = require('../controllers/author');
var router = express.Router();

const client = require("express-redis-cache")({
    host: process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME, 
    port: process.env.REDISCACHEPORT,
    auth_pass: process.env.REDISCACHEKEY
});


router.route('/').get(client.route(), controller.listAllPage);

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see, the first call uses the database, but the next few use the cache:
[image]

When I move this code out into ../middleware/cache.js, the code executes but a cache file is never created.  You can also see that each call continues to call the DB since there is no cache file:

```js
// ../middleware/cache.js
const cache = function(client){

    return (req, res, next) => {
        
        const client = require("express-redis-cache")({
            host: process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME, 
            port: process.env.REDISCACHEPORT,
            auth_pass: process.env.REDISCACHEKEY
        });

        // Simple test
        client.route();
        next();
    }
}
module.exports = cache;
```

```js
// route file
var express = require('express');
var cache = require('../middleware/cache');
var controller = require('../controllers/author');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(cache(), controller.listAllPage);

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay.... so the express-redis-cache client.route function returns middleware!  So you just return it:

```js
const cache = function(){
    const client = require("express-redis-cache")({
        host: process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME, 
        port: process.env.REDISCACHEPORT,
        auth_pass: process.env.REDISCACHEKEY
    });

    // Simple test
    return client.route();
}
```

I figured that out after a console.log(client.route());